# confusion about pthread_cond_wait

Tags: c, multithreading

With respect to the following code, my understanding is that thread 1 grabs a lock, checks the condition, unlocks the clock, set itself to sleep state. Afterwards, thread 2 claims the same lock and increment count, then awake the sleeping thread. My question is that the condition right now is still false, but it awakes the sleeping thread, what will happen? And also the condition variable is a set of threads, so what if there are a lot of threads execute the code simultaneously, how does wait() handle this situation? Finally please explain the correct execution sequence of this code, thank you very much!!!

```
thread 1:
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (!condition)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    /* do something that requires holding the mutex and condition is true */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

thread2:
  while(1){
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     count++;
     pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }
```

Comment: What do you think `while(!condition)` does? As long as the condition isn't true, thread 1 will just keep re-running the while loop's body, i.e. it will keep waiting for the condition again and again.

Comment: @immibis what does the 2nd unlock do? Just to unlock the lock wait() return?

Comment: Read a book. https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Programming_with_POSIX_Threads.html?id=_xvnuFzo7q0C

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that the condition right now is still false, but it
>   awakes the sleeping thread, what will happen?

That's why the `pthread_cond_wait` is in a `while` loop. It only gets out of the `while` loop when `pthread_cond_wait` unblocks **and** the condition is true.

And this is exactly what the [pthread_cond_wait man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) notes needs to be done.

> When using condition variables there is always a Boolean predicate
>   involving shared variables associated with each condition wait that is
>   true if the thread should proceed. Spurious wakeups from the
>   pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() functions may occur.
>   **Since the return from pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait()
>   does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the
>   predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return.**

(Emphasis mine).

Answer (score 0):

1) Thread 1 locks the mutex
2) Thread 1 unlocks the mutex (with pthread_cond_wait) 
3) Thtead 2 locks the mutex 
4) Thread 2 unlocks the mutex and sends the signal (pthraed_cond_signal) 5) Thread 1gets the mutex back 
6) Thread 1 unlocks the mutex